# How can I find out if there are windows above a control?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

If I have a Winforms control, is it possible to tell if there are windows (from any application) above it?  Basically, I need to know what parts of my control are actually visible on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy to P/Invoke, the EnumWindows function enumerates all top-level windows on the screen giving a HWND; from that you can get the non-client rectangle (GetWindowRect) to compare against your form bounds.

This won't account for windows with non-rectangular opaque areas (fancy skins for media players and the like), so you may get false positives for such a window occluding your control.

Answer (score 0):

In the Win32 API, you can use [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558(VS.85).aspx) to determine the topmost window at any given point. This won't tell you if your whole control is visible, but if you test all 4 corners it gives you pretty good odds.

Comment: Actually, I need to know exactly what is visible, so if half of my control is visible, I need to know that exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want this information?  Typically when people ask this question it's because they want to ensure that their UI is in the foreground if it's not.  And that usually is what happens just before they try to steal the focus away from the application which *does* have the foreground.

And foreground stealing is very, very, very bad.  People get REALLY upset when applications steal focus.

Having said that, either of the two techniques above would work - I think I'd prefer the EnumWindows/GetWindowRect/IntersectRect technique in Steve Gilham's answer.